# prove that $ab=1$ implies $ba=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a doubt how to prove:
*If the product of any pair of non-zero elements of $R$ is non-zero , prove that $ab=1$ implies $ba=1$.*

how shall I make use of the fact : product of any pair of non-zero elements of $R$ is non-zero i.e no zero divisors exist to prove this...

Comment: Apologies for the mis-fired answer and any confusion it may have caused. I have now deleted the "answer".

Comment: @amWhy just out of curosity ,I wanted to know in rings under which condition is there existence of a unique inverse...Please If you could help me..

Comment: When the non-zero elements of a Ring form a multiplicative group, then any element's right inverse is also a left inverse, and it is unique for that element.

Comment: @amWhy thanks for clarifying ...It seems to only occur in case of fields..

Comment: @patang: Probably $R$ is a ring? Next time, please add all assumptions and notations to the question. (This probably also lead amWhy to his (deleted) answer which deals with groups.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$$
ab=1 \implies aba=a \implies a(ba-1)=0 \implies ba=1
$$

Comment: wow!!nice trick..

Comment: One has to be a bit careful: $ax=0 \Rightarrow x=0$ is only allowed when $a \neq 0$. But if $a=0$, then the first equation shows $0=1$, i.e. the ring is trivial, and the the claim is clear anyway.